# How does this form work with input tags outside the <form> tags?

Tags: php, javascript, input

I am looking at the form code on this website: http://reallysuccessful.com/ottawa/ and noticed that there are `<input>` tags outside of the `<form>` tags.

I don't see any javascript that is making this work...

So how does it submit the data along with the other information that is actually in the `<form>` tags???

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's because it's set inside a `modal` in conjunction with `jQuery`.

Comment: I'm referring to the '<input>' tags near the top of the page, where people select the locations... before clicking the Continue javascript  button.

Comment: ^---« Consult my original comment.

Comment: `<input type="button" onclick="jQuery('#myModal').modal('show')" value="CONTINUE" />` (pulled from frame source).

Comment: That `Roger` is gonna love the `plug` ;-) (His Bootstrap's not working for him, btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is some javascript (you can find it at the bottom of the html-source, right before the `body` closes):

```
function updateArea() {
    var allVals = [];
    $('.areas :checked').each(function (i) {
        allVals.push((i != 0 ? "\r\n" : "") + $(this).val());
    });
    $('#wantedArea').val(allVals).attr('rows', allVals.length);
}
```

this puts information about the checkboxes into `#wantedArea`, wich itself is a hidden `textarea` inside the modal-dialogs `form`. from that point it gets posted together with the other form-fields, no javascript is involved at that point.

Comment: YES! Thanks! I'm still learning javascript so didn't catch this.

Answer (score -1):

the form is placed in the `model` with `id="final_form"` and post the values using jQuery javascript library.

Comment: thats just plain wrong. the form itself is simple html, no javascript is used to post the values to the server or something like that. javascript is only used to set the value of a `textarea` (`#wantedArea`). `#final_form` isn't used in that piece of code.